# FastAPI running on Google Cloud Run redirects POST request to GET

Tags: rest, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I am trying to do a simple POST request to FastAPI server running on Cloud Run. However for some reason my request is being redirected, and what is even more interesting it is redirecting to HTTP resource.

What I have checked so far

1. Protocol, I am posting using HTTPS not HTTP
2. Curl works
3. CORS: I've added following code to FastAPI server :

```
origins = [
    "http://localhost:5174",
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "*"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

4. Running fetch in Chrome dev tools :

```
fetch(`https://xxxx.run.app/plan/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            json: true,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                org,
                title,
                desc
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res => res.json())
          .then(console.log);
```

In response I got :

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xyz.ngrok.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://xxxxx.run.app/plan'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Edit: As @MatsLindh suggested, it was the trailing / that caused the redirection. Thanks

Comment: Is your endpoint registered as `/plan` and not `/plan/` as you're requesting? In that case a redirect will be issued, and if you're not running with your ASGI server configured to trust proxy headers (X-Forwarded-Proto and friends), only the `<proxy> - <your app>` protocol will be known to your application (which issues the redirect).

Comment: @MatsLindh, oh my, it was indeed the trailing backslash that caused the redirect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HTTP redirects do not specify the HTTP method - but some status codes imply the HTTP method (status code 303)). It is up to the client code to follow the HTTP Location header and also decide the request method. Since you control the backend, review the difference between status codes 301 and 308 [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#permanent_redirections).

Your backend code running in Cloud Run is probably not detecting the client protocol (http versus https) correctly. It is safe to always assume https in Cloud Run but you can use the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to write portable code [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto)